# Making an element solid?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I mean, I want to make an element like  in html. You know, nothing goes wrong and it has its own division. But in all of my activities look like everything is just in one place. How can I do that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.blunderer.materialdesignlibrary.views.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:mdl_title="CardView"
            app:mdl_description="A Basic CardView"
            app:mdl_normalButton="Normal"
            app:mdl_highlightButton="Highlight"
            app:mdl_imagePosition="none"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"/>


        <com.blunderer.materialdesignlibrary.views.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardview2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:mdl_title="127.0.0.1:8080"
            app:mdl_description="Konum: Yerel\nPing: 0 ms"
            app:mdl_imagePosition="none"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"/>

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

That's my xml.

Comment: Share your xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is you are using relative layout as parent layout and you are not assigning childs position Relative to each other.

What you can do :-

Option1

Replace relative layout with vertical orientated Linear Layout as root layout and you will realize all views are now aligned one below another. And your view will look 'solid' like a webpage.
It will make you feel like you are at home as I think like you are web developer and New to android.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_linear_layout.htm

Option 2

The right way is assign view position Relative to each other. You need to put view below or beside one another :-

http://androidexample.com/Relative_Layout_Basics_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=73&aaid=97

Option 3

Try to drag and drop views in xml viewer of ide. This Will works fir demo and but not recommended for real project.